# How do i print my list of students results without the punctuation?

Tags: python

The list is:

```
result = [("Imelda Thomas",74),("Craig Parr",90),("Eric Salisbury",58),("Laurence Mann",35),("Bill Walford",82),("David Harold",27),("Pamela Langley",43),("Sarah Boat",39),("Rachel Matthews",62),("Michaela Cunningham",69)]
```

I want it to print:

```
Imelda Thomas 74
Craig Parr 90
Eric Salisbury 58
Laurence Mann 35
Bill Walford 82
David Harold 27
Pamela Langley 43
Sarah Boat 39
Rachel Matthews 62
Michaela Cunningham 69
```

But the another problem is that this code that allows it to print in this way needs to allow the list to be changed in anyway E.G. get shorter, names changing

Comment: You should post what you have right now. SO likes people to show some effort first.

Comment: thanks - it works amazingly for something so simple ;)

Comment: Elliot, you should add your comment to the answer that solved your problem, and then it's kind to accept the answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way is:

```
for name, grade in result:
    print name, grade
```

Comment: Maybe use `for name, grade in result:` for clarity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the names and grades in the list you should use lists instead of tuples inside it:

```
result = [["Imelda Thomas", 74], ["Craig Parr", 90], ["Eric Salisbury", 58], ["Laurence Mann", 35], ...]
```

(square brackets instead of parentheses)

Now you can make changes to the list elements, for example, change Thomas's grade:

```
result[0][1] = 85
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some fancy look then it's an alternate answer

```
In [45]: from tabulate import tabulate

In [46]: result = [("Imelda Thomas",74),("Craig Parr",90),("Eric Salisbury",58),("Laurence Mann",35),("Bill Walford",82),("David Harold",27),("Pamela Langley",43),("Sarah Boat",39),("Rachel Matthews",62),("Michaela Cunningham",69)]

In [47]: print tabulate(result)
-------------------  --
Imelda Thomas        74
Craig Parr           90
Eric Salisbury       58
Laurence Mann        35
Bill Walford         82
David Harold         27
Pamela Langley       43
Sarah Boat           39
Rachel Matthews      62
Michaela Cunningham  69
-------------------  --
```